# Copy contents of a folder form a remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have a machine which I can SSH into, but the logs I need are all compressed separately in a folder. (/path/to/folder/log_folder/{log1.gz, log2.gz, log3.gz, log4.gz, ...})

My problem is: I don't have the privileges to upcompress them. I can copy them to my local machine, but I don't know how to do more than one at a time, and there are dozens of log files.

How can I either uncompress the logs on the remote machine, or copy them all to my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man scp`:

> -r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.

Answer (score 0):

For me work more fine `rsync`for this purpose

```
rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh" remote_user@remoteserver:/path/log/ /local/path/log/


# man rsync
```

From man rsync extract

```
NAME
   rsync - a fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool

SYNOPSIS
   Local:  rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]

   Access via remote shell:
     Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
     Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST

...
OPTIONS
...
  -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
...
   -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

And `man rsync` a loot fo information.

Comment: Could you expand upon what this command actually does?

Comment: `man rsync` // rsync it's a program for transfer files but optimize what you send. Work fine over ssh and not need remote daemon. Usually installed on all distros. https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to explain that. Your answer had come up on the review queue for poor quality.

Comment: You must be read man. My reply it's for question. My reply work for purpose on original question. If you like more information how work a command, simply, read documentation.